# Why is this div dropping down to the next line on window zoom out?

Tags: html, css

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hy3yb/)

I have a wrapper with 4 divs inside it that are all floated to the left and are in one line. When I zoom out, the 4th div drops to the bottom. The only possible problem I can think of is the width of the wrapper decreasing, thus causing it to not be able to contain the 4th one, but the wrapper has a fixed width so I'm sure thats not the problem.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="panel">
        <div id="panel1" class="panelcell"></div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panelcell"></div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panelcell"></div>
        <div id="panel4" class="panelcell"></div>
        <div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the css:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 1280px;
}
#panel{
    width:100%;
}

#panel .panelcell{
    width: 318.75px;
    height: 213px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.panelcell {
    background-color: gray;
}

#panel1{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of the problem is how the browser renders your widths of "318.75px" as you zoom out (since, well, you can't render 0.75px to the screen). Depending on how it's rounded as the elements scale with your zooming out, the elements' widths could end up adding to larger than that of the parent element, resulting in the last floated element being pushed to a new line.

The way (that I could think of) to solve this is using percentage widths, rather than decimal pixel widths. Changing your definition of `#panel .panelcell` to this should give you what you're looking for:

```
#panel .panelcell{
    width: 25%;
    height: 213px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `box-sizing: border-box` ensures that the 1px border is also taken into account when determining the 25% width of the element. Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hy3yb/3/) to show what this achieves. (The fourth element should not break to a new line as you zoom out.) If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Did not test it, but I think your guess about the wrapper not being able to contain the `<div>`'s is correct: 4*(318,75px+2px) = 1283px > 1280 px.

Just increase the width of your wrapper and it should be fine.

Comment: This math is wrong. That expression has a total of 8px worth of border. I only have 5px. The proper expression is (4 * 318.75) + 5, which equates to 1280.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your border-right 1px solid which is increasing the width over 1280

Comment: Can you expand on how I can fix this?